# PowerBI - Problem with parallel auto-update

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, auto-update

My dataset consists of a dozen tables, each with its own clickhouse query. Some of the requests are quite heavy, but each of them is executed separately, without exceeding the limit on the resources used.

But when the dashboard is updated **at the scheduled time**, all these requests start to be executed simultaneously, which causes confusion of the source and the resulting error: `DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded`.

Anyone have any ideas how to ask PowerBI to execute requests **sequentially** (not simultaneously) with a scheduled update?

Maybe it's possible to add M-code with "sleep" functions? Or something like this:

```
if (
    nothing updating now,
    let Source = Odbc.Query(...) in Source
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this in Power BI. The desktop does have a setting to enable/disable parallel loading of tables, but it doesn't work once you deploy to the service. The only option would be to use dataflows. You can then set a schedule to populate them, or set up a Power Automate/Logic app/Data Factory to hit the API to call them in some order.