# How can I disable parrllel data loading option for the dataset which is published in a Power BI workspace?

Tags: powerbi

I have issues every time the data was refreshed, but it works great in PBI Desktop once the "Enable parallel loading of tables" setting has been disabled. However, i need to publish this report online to my company's Workspace.  Once on the workspace the report fails to recalculate the tables again because i cannot find a way to disable the parallel loading of tabels.

Is there a setting for a web-published PBI report that will disable parallel loading of tabels?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67435665/powerbi-problem-with-parallel-auto-update

Comment: Hi @Jon, If we need to disable parallel data loading, I need to make data flows to overcome this problem. If so, should I need to make data flows for each table in my PBIX file?(for example: If I have 5 tables, I should make 5 dataflows)